# References for basic level Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, lie-groups

I an undergraduate math student with a decent background in abstract algebra. I am looking forward to studying Lie groups this summer...I want some you to suggest good references for the following topics

Differentiable manifolds; Tangent space. Vector fields; Frobenius theorem;
Relation between Lie sub-algebras & Lie subgroups; Cartan’s theorem on closed
subgroups; One parameter subgroups; Exponential maps; Adjoint representation;
Homogeneous spaces; Compact Lie groups; Symmetric spaces.

It would be great if the book/s covers the topic from a beginner's perspective.

Comment: A relatively straightforward book to learn from (although I don't think it covers all of the topics listed) is Loring Tu's book *An Introduction to Manifolds*. I think slightly more advanced is John Lee's book *An Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. I don't have any experience from the second suggestion, though, except for occasional referencing.

Comment: Don't use all-caps. Online it's generally regarded as shouting and is rude.

Comment: Warner's book, Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups have everything you want.

Comment: very few people survive Warner's book, though :-)

Comment: @user27126 I really have seriously mixed feelings about Warner's book. While it's well written,completely modern and has probably the broadest coverage of any text on the subject, it's brutally concise.More so then even "Adult Rudin" or Lang. Then again,Warner does explain things well & he has a surprisingly large number of examples and pictures.I think you'd have to be an exceptionally well-prepared graduate student to be able to really read it.

Comment: @user27126 cont. If you want a relatively rapid yet modern introduction, you should try Lawrence Conlon's beautiful text and follow it up with Poor's Differential Geometric Structures.Together, these books constitute an outstanding first year graduate course in differential geometry that's comprehensive and readable,yet not too wordy.Another very good-and sadly forgotten-follow up text to Conlon is T.J. Willmore's Riemannian Geometry-one of my favorites.