# Any book or lecture notes covering the following topics

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

I am going to do a course on Lie algebras and the prerequisites mentioned are: manifolds, tangent spaces, vector fields,  Lie bracket of  vector fields, exponential map.

I have only a working knowledge of these. I would like to know of any introductory book or lecture notes giving notions of all these topics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420766/references-for-basic-level-differentiable-manifolds-and-lie-groups?rq=1. Check this. Probably can help you.

Answer (score 0):

John Lee has two books, "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" and "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" that you might find helpful.